# Socket.io doesn't work with two promises and two sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tdlib

I'm trying to log into the telegram with this library: https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl,
I need to send the phone number and code through the frontend, the only way I saw to do this was using socket.io, when I use a promise with a socket it works normally, but when I do it twice nothing just happens.

Backend:

```
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
      console.log('a user connected');

      await client.login(() => ({
        getPhoneNumber: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            socket.on('phone:submitted', async (msg) => {
              resolve(msg);
            });
          });
        },
        getAuthCode: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            socket.on('code:submitted', async (msg) => {
              resolve(msg);
            });
          });
        },
      }));
    });
```

Frontend:

```
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.emit('phone:submitted', '+1234567890');
```

if I just put this: it works:

```
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
      console.log('a user connected');

      await client.login(() => ({
        getPhoneNumber: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            socket.on('phone:submitted', async (msg) => {
              resolve(msg);
            });
          });
        }
      }));
    });
```